# How do I create one to many relations in Kentico 12 page types?

Tags: kentico

So I have created a page type, for content entry.  The first part, 24 fields, sets up some headings and boolean fields that tell whether certain information and or buttons will be displayed on the page.  This works fine and I can customize the input form just the way we want it.  But the issue is how to now link in some one to many relationships.  For instance alternate redirect urls, multiple content paragraphs.  The idea is to have the same entry form for products as the users are currently using, the one to many escapes me.  I am using the MVC dev end.  I have created custom modules and associated web controls, but cannot figure how to add them to the page type layout.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So for these products you have additional data you want to include with it and that data is from these custom modules?

Comment: Essential, yes.  We have a mandate that we cannot change the current content input forms that the marketing dept uses.  About 24 single entry (table) fields for each product, then and additional 7 relational tables with between 5 and 15 fields each and anywhere from 1 to 20 rows for each product.

Answer (score 0):

For the module tables to link to page types you need a cross-reference table.  This table would hold say a GUID from the page type as well as a GUID from the module table.  How you link the page type and module record could be done on the page type (while this would be harder) OR you could create a custom UI module which would allow users to view the linking table and add or remove records.  This would be a listing of all the module table records and then allow you to select one module record and see or add many links to it.

Then in your page display, you simply do a custom query to that cross-reference table and join in the module table to get the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches with pros and cons for each.

You can use Related Pages to relate to other pages that contain your content (such as a Page that contains paragraph information).  My Relationships Extended Module can help with that.

You can use the content tree to store relationships, putting multiple items below the page and using the NodeAliasPath to find children of your certain page types (`DocumentHelper.GetDocuments("My.PageType").Path(YourParent.NodeAliasPath+"/%")`)

You can also use a multiple-selector, storing a guid or codename in a comma separated list on a single field (not greatest but it can get it done).

You can also create your own custom binding classes through the Modules, although you will need to make sure to configure things properly with the ObjectTypeInfo so it is handled properly in Kentico.  Again the Relationships Extended module can aid in creating interfaces to maintain that.

See [RelationshipsExtended](http://devtrev.com/MVC-Resources/Relationships-Extended)

And also [My Blog on this topic](http://devtrev.com/Trev-Tips-(Blog)/February-2018/This-or-That-Many-Item-Relationships)

And a [presentation on different data modeling with pros and cons](https://github.com/HBSTech/Presentation-DataModeling).